# Memory access error with JNA and byte[]

Tags: java, c++, windows, jna

Environment: Windows 32 bit, MSVC, Eclipse

The C code:

```
#define API2_API __declspec(dllexport)
extern "C" {
  API2_API bool ReadResult(void* data);
}

API2_API bool ReadResult(
  void* data)
{
  int x = *(char*)data; // <-- no error if this line deleted
  return false;
}
```

The Java code:

```
// API2: bool ReadResult(void* result_data);
public interface Api2 extends Library {
  public boolean ReadResult(byte[] result_data);
}

Api2 api = (Api2)Native.loadLibrary("Api2.dll", Api2.class);
byte[] result_data = new byte[10];
boolean ret2 = api.ReadResult(result_data);
```

The call fails with "invalid memory access". I have already experimented with other call types and String, int and int[] work just fine. My setup seems OK. This is the only one that fails.

I can run this under Visual Studio debugger and the incoming pointer looks valid but is not. Trying to dereference it crashes VS.

Yes, I know I could use Buffer or Memory or some other trick, but that isn't the question. The question is: why does this not work?

---

Edit: the error only happens if the passed in parameter is accessed. If the function returns immediately (by deleting the line shown) there is no error.

Comment: Is that C code compiled with a C or C++ compiler?

Comment: See tag: C++. Does it matter? The DLL is the same.

Comment: By default Java `boolean` maps to native `int`.  Make sure the sizes of your return types match up.  The size of `bool` is implementation-specific.

Comment: @technomage: Yes, I know. The call goes through InvokeInt() and the return value is cast correctly to a Java boolean. See edit: it only crashes if the argument is accessed. Without the line marked it completes normally.

Comment: Well, `C++` `bool` is a built-in type, while `C` `bool` is whatever typedef you used.  You said 'C code' in the question, yet tagged it C++, which is confusing: they are different languages.  I am unclear  your "other experiments": how, exactly, did they differ?  I am unclear how "InvokeInt" is fixing the problem that the return value size may or may not be an int.

Comment: The return value is _not_ "cast", nor can it be.  The underlying assembly code glue makes assumptions about the size of your return value based on what you tell it.   I would suggest changing this aspect to remove all possibility of error arising from it, rather than trying to explain it away.

Comment: The return type can _also_ affect the stack layout, which will most certainly affect whether your are able to successfully navigate your incoming arguments.  Try putting integer arguments before and after your "pointer" argument, with known values, then print them as well as the pointer value in hexadecimal form.  That will make it obvious whether your stack alignment is off.